# My Mac crashes and shuts down when charger is unplugged, not immediately

Tags: crash, power, power-management

Hey so my Macbook Pro (Retina 15" 2014 i7 2.6GHz, High Sierra (institute doesn't allow me to update)) is turning itself off randomly, and as far as I've figured out this will only occur when the power is unplugged. At first I found it being more common when my laptop was feeling quite hot, and perhaps even my laptop seems to start overheating when I unplug it? This is very possibly not the case though, I'm trying to find a pattern where there might not be one.

I reset the SMC and did all the other stuff listed on the apple website of "what to do if your mac keeps shutting off".

The screen seems to go off with a backlight still on for some time, and then either it gets stuck and I have to hold down power to shut it down, or it fully shuts down itself. This can occur after 3 hours of no problems using battery, or it can happen within 5 mins and then every 5 mins thereafter for the next 30-45 mins.

I have no sudo privileges fwiw, if there's no solution I can do myself, I'll take it to my institute whose laptop it is, but given current situation I'm trying to avoid making that journey.

Thanks!

Comment: Just spitballing here but considering the age of that laptop it could easily be a worn out battery. I have a MacBook Pro (mid-2015) and it is getting its battery replaced at Apple right now. So it might be that time...

Comment: If a laptop that belongs to the "institute" stops working, then you need to go to them to get it fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you have to make that journey as there’s really nothing you can do.

- if it’s the battery or hardware, which I suspect, it’s got to go in for service
- if it’s an update or macOS issue, your IT department will have to address since it’s locked down as you describe
- even some of the diagnostic procedures will require `sudo` access which you stated you don’t have means you have to take it in

When an IT department locks down an asset like yours, it’s best to let them handle things. They *should* have loaners and/or replacements at the ready.  Make sure when you communicate to them, emphasize that it *stops* your work (just some lingo to use to prioritize you in the  queue).

Answer (score -2):

May this will help you as it did me reaaaaly helped

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8220508?answerId=32800766022#32800766022